# ERROR: String list list instead of string list

Tags: sml

I have this function that results a string list:

```
fun get_substitutions1 ([],_) = []
| get_substitutions1 (x::xs,s) = case all_except_option(s,x) of
    NONE     => []  @get_substitutions1(xs,s)
  | SOME lst => lst @get_substitutions1(xs,s)
```

And this function that takes a string list list and a type:

```
fun similar_names(slist,full_name:{first:string,middle:string,last:string})=
let
fun aux(slist,acc)=
case full_name of
{first=a,middle=b,last=c} => case get_substitutions1(slist,a) of
[] => full_name::acc
| x::xs'  => full_name::  aux(xs',{first=x,middle=b,last=c}::acc)

in aux(slist,[])
end
```

And i get an error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree.

operator domain: string list list * 
                 {first:string, last:string, middle:string} list
operand:         string list * 
                 {first:string, last:string, middle:string} list
in expression:
   aux (xs',{first=x,middle=b,last=c} :: acc)
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

Well first of all you might wan't to indent your code so that it is readable.

It is quite obvious why you get the error you do. The function

```
fun get_substitutions1 ([],_) = []
  | get_substitutions1 (x::xs,s) =
    case all_except_option(s,x) of
      NONE => []@get_substitutions1(xs,s)
    | SOME lst => lst @get_substitutions1(xs,s)
```

has the type

```
val get_substitutions1 = fn : ''a list list * ''a -> ''a list
```

and you are trying to use the result of this function in your inner case expression where you take the tail of the returned list (type `'a list`) and use them in the recursive function call.

```
fun similar_names(slist,full_name:{first:string,middle:string,last:string})=
    let
      fun aux(slist,acc)=
          case full_name of
            {first=a,middle=b,last=c} =>
            case get_substitutions1(slist,a) of
              [] => full_name::acc
            | x::xs'  => full_name::  aux(xs',{first=x,middle=b,last=c}::acc)
    in aux(slist,[])
    end
```

However since your first argument of `aux` is used in `get_substitutions1`, that argument must be of type `'a list list`, but the `xs'` you use down in the recursive call is only of type `'a list`.

Comment: I know that get_substitutions1 results to a string list.But my helper function takes a string list list.I am confused because i want the recursion with the string list result.Can you help me?

Comment: If you know that, then why haven't you fixed it? Perhaps you should restate your question to be a bit more clean, as to what it really is that you don't understand

Comment: The only thing I can say more is that it would appear that you are using either the input or the results of `get_substitutions1` the wrong way.

Comment: I can't find another way to do what i want.I think my logic is correct but i'm losing something.At least,is it something obvious?